# Cannot get dictionary values in Django templates

Tags: python, html, django, templates, jinja2

I am trying to access the value of the class method which return dictionary. I function looks like this:

```
 class GetData:
def __init__(self, api_key, ip, interface):
    self.api_key = api_key
    self.asa_ip = ip
    self.interface = interface
    self.auth_headers = {'X-Auth-Token': api_key, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

def data(self):
    req = requests.get('https://{}:/{}/entries'.format(self.ip, self.interface),
                       headers=self.auth_headers, verify=False)
    json_response = json.loads(req.content)
    data = {}
    for items in json_response['items']:
    ...

    return data  #it return dictionary
```

In my view.py my code look like this:

```
   def class_data(request):
       interface_name = request.session.get('interface')
       ip = request.session.get('ip')
       api_key = request.session.get('api_key')
       peer = str(request.POST.get('Peer'))
       class_data = DataForm(interface_name, api_key, ip)
       return render(request, 'user/data.html', {'peer' : str(peer), 'class_data': class_data })
```

In my data.html I am trying to acces data in GetData class:

```
       <h5>Data</h5>
            <p> {{ class_data.data.peer.pfs_group }}</p>
```

I do not get any error and I see a blank page in browser. I allready tried to call class like this:

```
    {{ class_data.data[peer]['pfs_group'] }}
```

But when I do this, I get an error:

```
     django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: 
     Could not parse the remainder: '[peer]['pfs_group']' from 'vpn_data.data[peer]['pfs_group']'
```

What I am doing wrong??

Comment: Are you certain that you have `data` before you render `data.html` ?

Comment: Also have you tried `data['key_name']` instead of `data[key_name]` which doesn't have literals?

Comment: If I put string instead of dictionary I can see it in my page. I have tried both options, without success.

Comment: You are not using Jinja, you are using Django template language. That language does not support brackets (or parentheses). But note that your example doesn't make sense; if ClassName is a class, what is that `return` statement doing? Please show some real code.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have corrected my question, here is my real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `peer` is a variable, but when you use it as the key Django just sees it as a literal string.

You should do the lookup in the view and pass the resulting value to the template:

```
   peer = str(request.POST.get('Peer'))
   class_data = DataForm(interface_name, api_key, ip)
   peer_data = class_data[peer']
   return render(request, 'user/data.html', {'peer_data': peer_data })
```

...

```
{{ peer_data.pfs_group }}
```

Comment: Do You maybe know, is it possible to call object and insert in the variable in the template?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean unfortunately.

Comment: I would like to access data in template like this: {{ class_data.data[peer]['pfs_group'] }}. Is any possibility to do it?

Comment: Not with Django template language, no. You could switch to Jinja but that has its own issues.